# Ranking objects using least squares

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, least-squares, applications, sorting

I need to develop an application to automatically rank objects. This is the use case: I have a set of objects, all of which have the same set of properties. For example, a set of cars, all of which have weight, horsepower, tank volume etc. I want to assign different weights to these properties, but initially all I know is the order in which the users want these objects to be in. We can assume that this initial set is representative of the whole domain.

My idea is to store the data in a matrix $A$, in which the rows represent the objects and the columns represent the properties. The rows are in ascending order. Then I create a vector $b = (1, 2, \ldots, n)$ and solve the equation $Aw = b$ by least squares, where $w$ is the vector of weights. Once I have these weights, I can add or remove objects from my set, and I can find the new ranking by just computing the linear combination for each object and then sorting them. In other words, I compute a new $b$ every time there is a change in the set.

Then comes the second requirement: users may want to reorder the objects at any time. To implement this, I'm thinking about permuting the rows of $A$ according to the new order provided by the users, but keeping $b$ as it is, and recomputing $w$.

Does this idea make sense?

Comment: Your idea makes sense to me. Are you looking for alternative approaches?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that with your method, $w$ might have negative entries, whereas "weights" typically refer to non-negative numbers.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I'm just checking to see if there is any obvious flaw. One question that just occurred to me is: when solving the equation, is it guaranteed to preserve the order?

Comment: If the rows are linearly independent, then yes, the solution $w$ will necessarily give you the correct order because the equation will have an exact solution. If the rows are not linearly independent, things get a bit tricky

Comment: Well, they can't be linearly independent because there will be many more rows than columns.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure how well your method will work. I suspect it could be improved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative. First, to reiterate what I say below: let $a_i$ denote the $i$th row of $A$ as a column vector, i.e. the $i$th column of $A^T$. A weight vector $w$ will rank row $a_j$ as higher than $a_i$ if and only if $(a_j - a_i)^Tw > 0$.

Now, let $B$ denote the matrix $M$ whose rows are all vectors of the form $(a_j - a_i)^T$ for which $j > i$. We're looking for a vector $w$ such that, ideally, every entry of $Bw$ is positve. Note that such a $w$ specifies a hyperplane that separates the columns of $B$ from the vector $0$. By the [hyperplane separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem), this will be possible if and only if the vector $0$ is not an element of the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the rows of $B$.

With that established, we can definitively determine whether such a $w$ exists by solving the [convex optimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization)
$$
\min \|B v\|^2 \quad \text{subject to}\quad v_1 + \cdots + v_n = 0 \text{ and }v_i \geq 0 \quad i = 1,\dots,m.
$$
If this minimum is non-zero and $v_*$ is the vector $v$ that minimizes $\|Bv\|^2$, then taking $w = Bv_*$ will give us weights that produce the desired ranking. If the minimum is $0$, then no such vector exists.

---

Here is an alternative method to consider.

Suppose that $A$ has size $m \times n$, and that the rows of $A$ are sorted according to the desired ranking. Set $w$ equal to the vector $w = A^Tv$, where
$$
v = (1-m, 3-m,\dots,m-3,m-1)^T.
$$
You could normalize the weights however you like without affecting the resulting ranking. For instance, you could divide each entry of $w$ by $\sum_{k=1}^m |w_k|$.

---

The justification is as follows: let $a_i$ denote the $i$th row of $A$ as a column vector, i.e. the $i$th column of $A^T$. A weight vector $w$ will rank row $a_j$ as higher than $a_i$ if and only if $w^T(a_j - a_i) > 0$.

Let $S$ denote the set of all vectors of the form $a_j - a_i$ for which $j > i$. We're looking for a vector $w$ such that, ideally, $w^Tx > 0$ for every $x \in S$. My conjecture is that a good candidate for such a vector (if one does exist) is the sum
$$
w = \sum_{x \in S} x.
$$
This is the vector $w = A^Tv$ that I describe above.

Comment: Yes, that's a more sophisticated method than mine. I'm still struggling to see why $\sum_{x \in S} x = A^ Tv$. And, I know you said it's a conjecture, but what makes you believe that $w$ satisfies the property you described?

Comment: Regarding the first point: note that each element of $S$ can be written in the form $A^Tv_{ij}$, where $v_{ij}$ has a $-1$ in the $i$th spot and a $1$ in the $j$th spot. The vector $v$ is $\sum_{i<j}v_{ij}$. Regarding the second point, I don't have a strong justification.